# Unique constraint on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
        [userID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [fcode] [int] NULL,
        [scode] [int] NULL,
        [dcode] [int] NULL,
        [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_user_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [userID] ASC
    )
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

How do I add a unique constraint for columns `fcode, scode, dcode` with `t-sql` and/or `management studio`? `fcode, scode, dcode` must be unique together.

Comment: Does that mean that you can have many of the same fcode OR scode OR dcode but never two records with the same fcode AND scode AND dcode?

Answer (score 323, accepted):

By using the constraint definition on table creation, you can specify one or multiple constraints that span multiple columns. The syntax, simplified from [technet's documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx), is in the form of:

```
CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] 
(
    column [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,...n ]
)
```

Therefore, the resuting table definition would be:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [userID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fcode] [int] NULL,
    [scode] [int] NULL,
    [dcode] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_user_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [userID] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [UQ_codes] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [fcode], [scode], [dcode]
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 484):

If the table is already created in the database, then you can add a unique constraint later on by using this SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.User
  ADD CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE (fcode, scode, dcode)
```

Comment: Or `ADD CONSTRAINT ucCodes UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED` ?

Comment: If all columns fcode, scode, dcode are NULL, not applies constarint ?
If any column fcode, scode, dcode is NULL, not applies constarint ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: not entirely sure what you're asking - `NULL` is handled like any other value, which means: if you have a unique constraint across those three columns, there can **only** be a single row with each of them being `NULL`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443637/tsql-multi-column-unique-constraint-that-also-allows-multiple-nulls

Answer (score 70):

This can also be done in the GUI. Here's an example adding a multi-column unique constraint to an existing table.

1. Under the table, right click *Indexes*->Click/hover *New Index*->Click *Non-Clustered Index...*

[image]

2. A default Index name will be given but you may want to change it. Check the *Unique* checkbox and click *Add...* button

[image]

3. Check the columns you want included

[image]

Click *OK* in each window and you're done.

Comment: NOTE: This option is not available if you already have the table open in design view. So close the design tab first before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [TSQL2012]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_1]    Script Date: 11/22/2015 12:45:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [seq] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [cat] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Table_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [name] ASC,
    [cat] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.