# TSQL Multi Column Unique Constraint That Also Allows Multiple Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, filtered-index

I am currently doing some migration from MS Access to SQL Server. Access allows multiple Nulls in unique indexes where as SQL Server does not... I've been handling the migration by removing the indexes in SQL Server and adding filtered indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1_notnull 
ON tblEmployee(col1) 
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to implement a composite or multi-column "filtered" indexes... or if this is really possible as I've found no examples in researching it.

I do have an idea to implement it by creating filtered indexes like so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1col2_notnull 
ON tblEmployee (col1, col2) 
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

And then adding a second filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col2col1_notnull 
ON tblEmployee (col1, col2) 
WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
```

But I'm not sure if this would even work let alone be the best method. Guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using check constraints? At least then you wouldn't need to have several indexes per table

Comment: @JamesZ I am only familiar with using Check Constraints in the context of turning them off and on for migration purposes... so I will research it. Thanks...

Comment: Fix it in data design.  Create a FK table that does not allow nulls.  Then just create a view with a left join to present the null.

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_col1col2_notnull ON tblEmployee(col1,col2) WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL and col2 is not null`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I've actually tried this using the 'OR' operator which SQL did not like. It does accept the AND operator as in your example.  My concern is that it will not except multiple nulls unless both columns are null with the AND operator? ... Is my logic incorrect in that?

Comment: No it will allow many double nulls

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Forgive me... I didn't phrase the question correctly. What if only one of the columns has multiple nulls and not both?

Comment: It will index only rows where both cols are not null, so you can insert any count of any combination where at least one col is null

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri ok, thanks. Please add it as answer so I can vote it as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the following index to index only non nullable columns:

```
create table tblEmployee(col1 int, col2 int)
go

create unique nonclustered index idx_col1col2_notnull ON tblEmployee(col1,col2) 
where col1 is not null and col2 is not null
go

--This Insert successeds
insert into tblEmployee values
(null, null),
(null, null),
(1, null),
(1, null),
(null, 2),
(null, 2)

--This Insert fails
insert into tblEmployee values
(3, 4),
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can combine several indexes to keep unique resctrictions in all fields where a nullable field is null

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    [Idx_1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idx_2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idx_3] [int] NULL,
    [no_index_field] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_3_fields
ON MyTable (Idx_1, Idx_2, Idx_3)
WHERE Idx_3 IS NOT NULL;

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_2_fields
ON MyTable (Idx_1, Idx_2)
WHERE Idx_3 IS NULL;
```