# Allowing only unique combination in sql table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a sql table in net frame work in VS that has room and user id ,but I want that only one of each combination can exist in the table:

```
Want:
room --- user id
1           2
1           3
3           2
2           1
1           1
3           1
 
Dont want:
room --- user id
1           2
1           2
```

how can I make it so that only unique combination can be entered?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unique constraint on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474291/unique-constraint-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3):

You can enforce uniqueness using a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_t_room_userid on t(room, user_id);
```

or:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_room_userid
    unique (room, user_id);
```

Comment: if i enter this line and i try to add a non unique combination it wont let me?

Comment: @RatLord122 . . . You will get an error if you attempt to add a row that violates the constraint or index.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want Room, UserId to be the PRIMARY KEY on that table.

```
CREATE TABLE Occupancy
(
    RoomId INT NOT NULL
    ,UserId INT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_Occupancy PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RoomId,UserId)
)
```

When you try to insert a duplicate value:

```
INSERT dbo.Occupancy (RoomId,UserId)
VALUES
(1,1)
,(1,2)
,(1,1)
GO
```

You will get a message like this:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Occupancy'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.Occupancy'. The duplicate key value is
> (1, 1).